# Is dynamic memory allocation be done by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

dynamic memory allocation by pointers

what is the link between pointers and dynamic memory allocation . why do we use pointers for
dynamic memory allocation . whenever we use new operator we use only pointer variables why?
can anyone explain with an example

Comment: Pointers are pointers, dynamic memory allocation yields pointers.

Comment: new allocates something and gives you an address where it is. What you´re going to do with this address? Save it in a variable first before doing anything else? Right, and what kind of variable is meant for addresses? ...

Comment: Memory allocation dynamically using `new` will return you a address of memory chuck which you requested, which is assigned/hold by pointer type and not by any other means.

Comment: Looks like you start C++, in this case it is better to look at vectors first. That's simpler to understand and easier to use. Experienced programmmers only use C++ pointers when needed, otherwise they avoid it

Answer (score 1):

According to your question to start with you need not programming but real life example.

Imagine you live in your ordinary flat, it has its own address and on the door you can see big sign "Robin Mandela". It's like static memory allocation. On the start of your program you have some room in memory and a name associated with it. On every vacation you fly to other country where you rent a room in a hotel. You can live one year in one room, another year in another room and even change room during your vacation. You may even not really be interested in what room exactly you will live in, but you need to know that you precisely will have one to live in.

When you ask for dynamic memory allocation, you get some portion of memory. This memory can be allocated almost anywhere, like a room in hotel, and of course you need a key with number to know where to find it. A pointer is like that number on the key - it grants you access to your allocated data.
Also one year you may decide not to go on vacation and rent a room at all. You can't do this with your flat - you have just got it, live there or not. It's like static memory in program.

Answer (score 0):

The size and location (memory address) of objects of automatic and static storage duration is known at compile time. The objects can be accessed through *variables* and the compiler handles the memory implicitly.

Dynamic memory on the other hand, is allocated at run time, as the name implies. Because it happens at runtime, the compiler can not have knowledge of where the memory is allocated and therefore can not handle the memory for the you. You must access the memory using it's address.

*How to get the address of dynamically allocated memory?*

It is returned by the `new` operator which allocates the memory and constructs the object. Since using dynamic memory just in one statement is not useful, you must store the address in a variable.

*What type of variable can store a memory address of an object?*

A pointer type. The type of the return value of a new-expression is a pointer to the type of object you constructed.

An example:

```
void foo() {
    Foo f; // The object of type Foo has automatic storage and can be accessed through the variable `f`.
    Foo* f_ptr; // The pointer object has automatic storage and is not yet initialized.
    new Foo; // Bad! The dynamically allocated memory can not be accessed in any way (it has leaked).
    f_ptr = new Foo; // The address of another dynamically allocated object is assigned to the f_ptr variable. The object is accessible through this pointer.
    delete f_ptr; // Dynamically allocated objects must be deleted explicitly.

    // f and f_ptr are destroyed automatically when the scope ends. If the memory pointed by f_ptr was not deleted before this, the memory would leak.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is a bit nonsensical. The keyword `new` is for allocating memory on the heap and returns either a pointer to the allocated object or throws a `std::bad_alloc` if allocation fails. It's in a sense like asking why `int main(int argc, char** argv)` returns an int.

In C++ you have two address spaces to work with; the stack and the heap.

Generally you want to use the heap for allocating your objects and pass them to functions either by reference, the preferred way, or by pointer. In some cases you can't use the stack, mainly when you either don't know how long the object you are creating is going to be alive or when you know that the object should live longer than the scope that creates it. For those cases you should be using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if you are using C++11 since the object will be deleted automatically when it's no longer needed.

Use of the keyword `new` is generally discouraged and should only be used when you're certain that neither of the above works.

To read up on the operator new:

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)
- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29)

shared_ptr:

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Difference between stack and heap:

- [learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)

Answer (score 0):

The function you use (for example: `malloc()` in c) try to get a part of the memory with the length you asked and then it gives you the address of this part of the memory if the allocation was successful else it gives you a 0 (in c and c++ at least). 
(When you want to have memory for an array of n items, you must ask for n * item size and you will get the address of the array which is also the address of the first element of your array in fact.)

Example: I want an array of 10 integers

```
// ask for allocation and get the address of the memory 
int * my_array = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));   
// you must verify that the allocation was successful 

if(my_array != 0) {
    // the system gave you the memory you need 

    // you can do your operations 
    //  " * my_array " and " my_array[0] " have the same meaning  
    my_array[0] = 22; 
    * my_array  = 22; 
    // This two lines make the same thing : the put 22 in the memory at the adresse my_array 

    // same thing for  " *(my_array + 9*sizeof(int)) " and " my_array[9] "  
    my_array[9] = 50; 
    *(my_array + 9*sizeof(int)) = 50; 
    // This two lines make the same thing : the put 50 in the memory at the adresse  my_array + 36 

    // 36 = 9*4 (sizeof(int) = 4 in most cases)  

    free(my_array); //always free the memory to give back the memory to the system and do not "lost it"
}
```

It is the same in c++ but you replace `malloc` by `new` and `free` by `delete`. They are keyword but you can see them as functions to understand what it is done.